# Error by create secure_channel in grpc of python

Tags: python, grpc

grpc was installed using pip. I tried to use it and I got an error. I looked for errors, but I could not find a solution.
The environment through uname is as follows.

env

```
uname -s -> Linux
uname -r -> 3.10.65
uname -m -> aarch64
```

code

```
import grpc
creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(open('roots.pem').read())
channel = grpc.secure_channel('myservice.example.com:443', creds)
```

error log

```
24061 ssl_transport_security.c:655] Could not set ephemeral ECDH key.
24061 security_connector.c:774]   Handshaker factory creation failed with TSI_INTERNAL_ERROR.
```

Comment: I'm also experiencing this in node.js. I wonder if they ever found a solution. https://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 0):

(I love that xkcd comic.. I feel that way all the time)

I solved this on arm64, here's how:

Under-the-hood `grpcio` uses `boringssl` if an environment variable is *not applied* to use the system's ssl. I believe the issue seen is with `boringssl` actually. Assuming you have `openssl`, `libssl1.0.0` and `libssl-dev` installed, and you have already installed grpcio via `pip` or `pip3`.. then, you would do the following:

First download the [grpcio source](https://pypi.org/project/grpcio/#files) from PyPi.

```
pip3 uninstall grpcio

tar -xvf grpcio-<version>.tar.gz
cd grpcio-<version>/

GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=True python3 setup.py install
```

I'm sure setting `GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=True` before your `pip3` install would work also, but I haven't tested that. The above solution fixed my issue.